# PHPMailer funciona com Gmail mas não com Hotmail/Live

Tags: php, phpmailer, email

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
require'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com'; 
$mail->Password = 'senhadoemail';
$mail->SingleTo = true; 

$mail->From = "email@gmail.com"; 
$mail->FromName = "nomedousuario"; 
$mail->addAddress("emaildestinatario@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "assunto do email"; 
$mail->Body = "conteudo do email";

if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Erro ao enviar Email:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!"
}
?>
```

Este código funciona normalmente, enviando e-mails de um remetente que tenha uma conta Gmail para qualquer outra conta, o problema é que ao mudar para o Live/Hotmail ele não funciona.
As mudanças que tentei fazer foram as seguintes:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com'; 

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
```

Mudei também o email do remetente para o fim **@hotmail.com**.
O erro que recebo é: `SMTP connection failed()`.
Rodo este código no *localhost* e gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: na verdade esta pergunta se trata do e-mail utilizando o live/hotmail, até mesmo porque utilizando o gmail o código está em pleno funcionamento

Comment: Roberto, ajustei o título para refletir o que entendi ser seu problema. Tente fazer títulos que descrevam rapidamente o problema; "Ajuda com X" não explica nada para quem vê sua pergunta na página principal.

Comment: Ah sim, pensei que o problema fosse o mesmo. Já exclui o comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Ative o Debug:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```

O SMTPSecure nao é 'tsl'. é sim 'tls':

```
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Quando eu vou enviar para o hotmail preciso mudar a porta para 587:

```
 $mail->Port = 587;
```

Exemplo de envio padrão pego na documentação do [Phpmailer no Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer):

```
<?php 

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'XXXXXXXX';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXX';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('XXXXXXXXhotmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('XXXXXXX@hotmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Tentei essas mudanças e ainda não consegui enviar o e-mail, o erro agora é de código 550.

Comment: Se você puder postar um pedaço de seu código aqui, seria de grande utilidade

Comment: @Roberto reeditei a resposta com um exemplo.