# SMTP Error: The following recipients failed do hotmail para dominiodaempresa

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho um formulário em html que o usuário vai digitar o nome, email, assunto e mensagem, considerando que o usuário poderá digitar email do hotmail, gmail, etc..., e quando confirma estou utilizando o código php abaixo para tentar mandar a mensagem para o meu email, utilizando o `PHP Mailer`, porém ocorre o seguinte erro:

> SMTP Error: The following recipients failed

Percebi que esse erro ocorre somente quando o `$mail->From` é do *hotmail*. Se eu colocar o mesmo *email* do `$mail->Username` não ocorre o erro e envia o *email* normalmente.

Já pesquisei e tentei praticamente todas alternativas que indicam na internet mas nenhuma deu certo, alguém poderia me dar uma ideia de onde possa estar o problema? talvez eu não esteja no caminho certo e gostaria de saber se é possível enviar um email de qualquer domínio para o meu email da empresa ?

```
<?php 
    require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    require('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
    require('phpmailer/class.pop3.php');

    $to = "thiago.falcao@methodinformatica.com.br"; // this is your Email address       
    $name = $_POST['nmContato'];    
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $subject = $_POST['assunto'];
    $message = $name . " enviou a mensagem:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['txt_contato'];  

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'email-ssl.com.br';
    $mail->Port = 465;  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = 'thiago.falcao@methodinformatica.com.br';
    $mail->Password = 'senhadoemail';
    $mail->From = $from; //o erro ocorre quando esse valor é thiago.friedman@hotmail.com
    $mail->FromName = $name;    
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;   
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
?> 

            <form class="form-horizontal" action="email.php" method="post" id="formContato">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="nmContato">Nome</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8" id="div_nmContato">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nmContato" id="nmContato">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8" id="div_email">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="assunto">Assunto</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8" id="div_assunto">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto">
                      </div>
                    </div>                          
                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="txt_contato">Mensagem</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8" id="div_mensagem">
                        <textarea id="txt_contato" name="txt_contato" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>  

                  <button id="btnContato" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:149px;">Enviar</button>                
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_limpa_contato">Limpar</button>                                                  
            </form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Creio que para o from ser @hotmail tem que usar a autenticação do hotmail: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/200541/3635

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99443/phpmailer-funciona-com-gmail-mas-n%C3%A3o-com-hotmail-live

Comment: não é uma duplicata, pesquisei todas essas perguntas antes de publicar aqui, tentei @GuilhermeNascimento mas não deu certo

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento SMTP ERROR: Password command failed, o problema é que assim, essa página que envia o email, é a página de Contato do site da empresa, então gostaria que aceitasse qualquer domínio de email, e enviasse para o email da empresa, caso isso seja impossível com o phpmailer, poderia me orientar com outro componente

Comment: Devo ter feito gato por lebre na marcação, @GuilhermeNascimento. Mas já anexaram o segundo link que postei.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vou anexar uma imagem do formulário e tentar deixar mais claro o que to querendo fazer

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz a edição explicando melhor o problema e inclui o html

Comment: Pronto, respondido

Answer (score 3):

Muitas hospedagens bloqueiam "maquiar" o remetente, isto para evitar que *SPAMMERS* façam uso desta pratica, então não terá como conectar a um SMTP especifico e alterar o `to:`, o servidor vai "negar"

Pelas configurações presumo que seja locaweb, pelo que me recordo eles também tem essa politica restrita para evitar SPAMs:

```
$mail->Host = 'email-ssl.com.br';
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Não quer dizer que você é um SPAMMER, só quer dizer que spammers fazem uso disto e então é melhor bloquear a todos.

O que você pode fazer é usar o `Reply-To:` ao invés de `To:`

```
$name = $_POST['nmContato'];    
$from = $_POST['email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'email-ssl.com.br';
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = 'thiago.falcao@methodinformatica.com.br';
$mail->Password = 'senhadoemail';

$mail->AddReplyTo($from, $name); //AQUI vai o reply-to:

$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

### Nota extra

Quando enviar para o servidor de produção remova esta linha `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;`, os dados que são exibidos acaso ocorra algum erro podem ser sensíveis.

Comment: obrigado pela atenção Guilherme, mas continua o mesmo erro, percebi que no erro não mostra o email do hotmail e sim root@localhost.com, SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 504 5.5.2 <root@localhost>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman não é o mesmo erro, a mensagem é **totalmente** diferente, vou tentar ajustar e já te aviso.